# Running Elixir app on Windows: Can't set short node name

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I built an Elixir app using `mix release` and when I run it using `.\_build\prod\rel\prod\bin\prod start`, I get the following error:

```
2020-02-08 19:57:52.981000
    args: []
    format: "Can't set short node name!\nPlease check your configuration\n"
    label: {error_logger,info_msg}
```

I looked into `fsutil` and changing my computer name (Windows 10) but no help.

I also tried what @aleksei mentioned but no luck:

`.\_build\prod\rel\prod\bin\prod start --sname zpc`

My mix.exs has the following:

```
  def project do
    [
      app: :km,
      releases: [
        prod: [
          include_executables_for: [:unix, :windows],
          steps: [:assemble, :tar]
        ]
      ],
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.9",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end
```

The env.bat.eex has the following:

```
@echo off
rem Set the release to work across nodes. If using the long name format like
rem the one below (my_app@127.0.0.1), you need to also uncomment the
rem RELEASE_DISTRIBUTION variable below.
rem set RELEASE_DISTRIBUTION=km
set RELEASE_NODE=<%= @release.name %>@127.0.0.1
```

Comment: It’s extremely hard to tell what’s wrong based on the above. Does explicit node name setting work `.\_build\prod\rel\prod\bin\prod --sname my_short_name start `?

Comment: No, I get the same error. I've also added more info to the post.

Comment: Comment the last line in env.bat.eex out.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! If you make it answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default template for `env.bat.eex` is configured to work with releases across nodes and depends on the `@release.name` module variable to be set.

To run the release with short node name, simply comment everything inside `env.bat.eex`:

```
@echo off
rem Set the release to work across nodes.
rem If using the long name format like
rem   the one below (my_app@127.0.0.1),
rem   you need to also uncomment the
rem   RELEASE_DISTRIBUTION variable below.
rem
rem set RELEASE_DISTRIBUTION=km
rem set RELEASE_NODE=<%= @release.name %>@127.0.0.1
```